# How to get the row number of the selected value of UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView in my viewController. I can get the value of the row number of the selected value in the picker from the delegate method

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

But in my case, I need to get the row number of the selected component as soon as the view appears. Is there a way to get the row number/trigger the delegate method as soon as the view appears.

Comment: then for that you should count your picker array that much row available in pickerview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use [selectedRowInComponent](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/selectedRowInComponent%3a)

> selectedRowInComponent:
>
> Returns the index of the selected row in a given component.
>   - (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component Parameters
>
> component
>
> ```
> A zero-indexed number identifying a component of the picker view.
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> A zero-indexed number identifying the selected row, or -1 if no row is
>   selected. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```
>
> See Also
>
> ```
> – selectRow:inComponent:animated:
> ```
>
> Related Sample Code
>
> ```
> iPhoneCoreDataRecipes
> ```
>
> Declared In UIPickerView.h

Answer (score 0):

you use this for select in pickerview

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
   {
      NSString *str= [yardsArray objectAtIndex:row];

   }
```

use this code when view will load

```
 -(void)ViewDidLoad
  {
   NSString *str= [yardsArray count];
  }
```

Comment: I need to get the row number of the currently selected value, when the view appears

Comment: Ok for that you should do with selection indicator in PickerView and check the index path of array where selection indicator stopped or available.

Answer (score -1):

in viewDidLoad

travers the array of your objects and match object of which you want to find out the row
and tell me if this is the solution